# waiting complete a code after run other method

Tags: android

I want to run two methods in onCreate method but I want to firstly run this

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.example.anket1");
            Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
            startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

after when complete above code run Asynctask method new `DownloadFileFromURL().execute(Icerik);` How can I do this? Code is below.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // starting new Async Task

        try {

            Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.example.anket1");
            Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
            startActivity(uninstallIntent);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }


        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(Icerik);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sims like you have to work on callback event , what i mean is you defiantly want one callback that application which you wanted to delete is done or not.

so do one thing go to this url
http://www.codeitive.com/0xzgVgXWPV/is-it-possible-to-get-actiondelete-intent-callback.html

you will get your answer !!

When you send a Intent.ACTION_DELETE,if the app is uninstalled completely,you can receive a broadcast in your BroadcastReceiver,then you can do whatever you want.

Happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult` instead, and run `DownloadFileFromUrl` from there.

Have a look to [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities) for more information on Activities.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, DELETE_REQUEST);
...
protected void onActivityResult((int requestCode, int resultCode,
         Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == DELETE_REQUEST) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               // Start your AsyncTask
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: how can I use startActivityForResult in my code can you show it?

Comment: Picked directly from the linked page.